# predicate typescript

Tags: typescript, типы

Нашел вот такую доку по predicates и хочу сделать +/- по аналогии
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Пытаюсь написать свой код:

```ts
type CtorType<T extends Animal> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T
}

class Animal {
  static isAnimal<T extends Animal>(animal: T): animal is T { // animal is T - не работает
    const Ctor = (this as any) as CtorType<T>  // тут не понятно, без явного as any, даже не компилится ????
    return animal instanceof Ctor
  }

  name: string

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super('Rabbit')
  }
}

const rabbit: Animal = new Rabbit()

const isRabbit = (animal: Animal): animal is Rabbit => { // animal is Rabbit - не работает
  return animal instanceof Rabbit
}

if (Rabbit.isAnimal(rabbit)) {
  type MyAnimal1 = typeof rabbit // type MyAnimal = Animal
}

if (isRabbit(rabbit)) {
  type MyAnimal2 = typeof rabbit // type MyAnimal = Animal
}

if (rabbit instanceof Rabbit) {
  type MyAnimal3 = typeof rabbit // type MyAnimal3 = Rabbit
}
```

Хочу добавить в базовый класс статичный метод `isAnimal`, который проверял - порожден ли инстанс от соответствующего класса, чтобы потом внутри блока `if`, если это так, применял соответствующий тип. Но у меня что-то не выходит. `Rabbit.isAnimal(rabbit)`

Далее написал еще более простую функцию `isRabbit`, которая уже явно проверяет - происходит ли инстанс от класса `Rabbit`. Тут тоже внутри блока `if` все равно тип Animal, причем если в условии явно написать `rabbit instanceof Rabbit`, то все ок

Comment: такое? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeAoa0IBcx9FhpEIEU0AKANzQFcBTALmjHgE8BKN+kZmRgAVABblhnAA5MAPJVQgAfJhy5oAJyb4GG+NH6DE8Ah2BMA9gDNo+cRADcagL5Y1AEyagwW6PDDIrHj4GsYA5k5qwBYmIQzA+BYa1P6BbASh8GHcquq29gB0qUzQALx+AUxOuK6uWN5Q0ABKYABGrYj40EwAHvhM8O4wCmi5wUQkQiMgdIxBHDx8c0LNbR1d2HlaOnoGy8am8ObW+eTV0K640bEa8YnJORh4DDLJAOQt7Z1vObVu1wRNGtOmwFmU-EwAO6rL74ajcSKIGzUT7rArkabUDTA-DcR5qK4xCAWEBMAogCxhagAAwAJBgAFIAZQA8gA5AoZcJIzhYnHcZwrabUhFYVxAA

Answer (score 1):

Typescript иногда (но редко) делает довольно неявные вещи.

В данном случае `Rabbit.isAnimal` не работает потому что дженерик в `isAnimal` привязан конкретно к `Animal` и не зависит от того кто его наследует.
Использование же `T extends typeof this` не работает в статических методах (увы).

Конструкция `animal is Rabbit` не будет работать до тех пор пока класс `Rabbit` не имеет како-либо отличительное свойство/метод от `Animal`, даже приватный. Пример:

```typescript
class Rabbit extends Animal {
    private legLength = 5 // То самое отличие от Animal
    constructor() {
        super('Rabbit')
    }
}

if (isRabbit(rabbit)) {
    type AnimalType = typeof rabbit // AnimalType is Rabbit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> static isAnimal<T extends Animal>(animal: T): animal is T { // animal is T - не работает
> ```

Ну наоборот же:

```
static isAnimal<T>(animal: T): animal is Animal
```

---

> ```
> if (isRabbit(rabbit)) {
>   type MyAnimal2 = typeof rabbit // type MyAnimal = Animal
> }
> ```

Тайпскрипт использует структурную типизацию, а у тебя классы `Rabbit` и `Animal` ничем не отличаются.

Добавь кролику любое отличие от животного и всё заработает:

[image: скриншот]